# Python-Caja Add Context Menu Entry

Tags: python, mate, context-menu, caja

I added an item to the context menu but I have some problems that I don't know how to solve:

1. Notepadqq opens on mouse hover and not on mouse click
2. How can I pass the path of the file to open?
3. Is there a way to indicate where in the menu it should appear? (optional)

   ```
   import os

   from gi.repository import Caja, GObject

   class ColumnExtension(GObject.GObject, Caja.MenuProvider):
       def __init__(self):
           pass
       def menu_activate_cb(self, menu, file):
           os.system("/usr/bin/notepadqq & pid=$!")

       def get_file_items(self, window, file):
           item = Caja.MenuItem(name='ExampleMenuProvider::Foo2', 
                                 label='Notepad++', 
                                 tip='',
                                 icon='')
       item.connect('activate', self.menu_activate_cb, file)
       return item,
   ```

Comment: For more productive results ask on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ too.